# How to show native popup using Gulp

Tags: notifications, gulp

I am  working on **Gulp build process** for automation. I have created a Gulp task for creating signed APK of android. Now I want to **show a notification popup** so that I can come to know my android APK is built.

Is there any way to show native popup in Gulp process?

I have done research and found [**node-notifier**](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-notifier) and **[gulp-notify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-notify)** modules but both are not working for me. Please help

**As per posted answer,**

I have tried with following, but no help... I am not getting notification. Does it requires Windows Toaster Support... I am using **Windows 8.1 Pro**.

```
gulp.task('notifier', function(){
    notify('Running from notifier task', 'Everything looks good');
});

function notify(title, message) {
    // Load dependencies
    var path = require('path');
    var notifier = require('node-notifier');
    var notifyOptions = {
        title: title,
        message: message,
        //icon: path.join(__dirname, 'coulson.jpg'), // Absolute path (doesn't work on balloons)
        sound: true, // Only Notification Center or Windows Toasters
        wait: true // Wait with callback, until user action is taken against notification
    };

    // start notifier
    notifier.notify(notifyOptions);
}
```

Comment: I use node-notifier and it works like a charm. What do you have that doesn't work?

Comment: I am not sure why it's happening. when I have called `notifier.notify()`, it returned undefined in console. Did you encountered with any such error?

Comment: Can you update the question with your gulp task and the console output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is too late after asking the question, but I thought it's good to record my solutions here.
So there are different commands to show a native popup for different OS.

**1. Windows**

Use the command `msg * <Your_Message_Here>`, for example, `msg * Hello World`.
This popup closes automatically after 1 minute.

**2.iOS**

Use the command

`osascript -e 'tell app \"System Events\" to display dialog \"<Your_Message>\" with title \"<Your_Title>\"'"`

and then you can execute these commands using node `exec`,

```
var WINDOWS_POPUP = "msg * MESSAGE";
var MAC_POPUP = "osascript -e 'tell app \"System Events\" to display dialog \"MESSAGE\" with title \"SUCCESS\"'";

function execCMD(cmd, cb) {
    exec(cmd,
    {
        cwd: './',
        maxBuffer: 2048 * 2048
    },
    function (err, stdout, stderr) {
        plugins.util.log(stdout);
        plugins.util.log(stderr);
        if (err) {
            cb(err);
        } else {
            cb(null,stdout);
        }
    });
}
/**
 * Rename android apk
 */
gulp.task('copyAPK', function () {
    return gulp.src(APK_PATH)
        .pipe(plugins.if(args.signedAPK, plugins.rename(APK_NAME)))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(releaseDirName + '/Android/'))
        .on('end', function () {
            plugins.util.log(plugins.util.colors.green('Good Job! Your APK is ready at following location : ') + plugins.util.colors.cyan(releaseDirName + '/Android/' + APK_NAME))
            execCMD(WINDOWS_POPUP.replace('MESSAGE', 'Good Job! Your APK is ready at following location : ' + releaseDirName + '/Android/' + APK_NAME), function () {
            })
        });
});

/**
 * Copy generated IPA
 */
gulp.task('copyIPA', function () {
    return gulp.src(IPA_PATH)
        .pipe(plugins.rename(IPA_NAME))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(releaseDirName + '/iOS/'))
        .on('end', function () {
            plugins.util.log(plugins.util.colors.green('Good Job! Your IPA is ready at following location : ') + plugins.util.colors.cyan(releaseDirName + '/iOS/' + IPA_NAME))
            execCMD(MAC_POPUP.replace('MESSAGE', 'Good Job! Your IPA is ready at following location : ' + releaseDirName + '/iOS/' + IPA_NAME), function () {
            })
        });
})
```

Hope this will help someone in scripting :).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

Make sure these are installed by running install once again

**Install**

```
npm install path node-notifier --save-dev
```

**Task**

```
gulp.task('notifier', function(){

    notify('Running from notifier task', 'Everything looks good');
);
```

**Notifier Function**

```
function notify(title, message) {

    // Load dependencies
    var path = require('path');
    var notifier = require('node-notifier');

    var notifyOptions = {
        title: title,
        message: message,
        icon: path.join(__dirname, 'coulson.jpg'), // Absolute path (doesn't work on balloons)
        sound: true, // Only Notification Center or Windows Toasters
        wait: true // Wait with callback, until user action is taken against notification
    };

    // start notifier
    notifier.notify(notifyOptions);
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Wilmer, let me give a try for this.

Comment: Wilmer need your help again. I have tried with it but not helping. Is icon a compulsory attribute for notification?

Comment: You can omit icon all together. That path does not exist in your machine., but it should work anyway.

Comment: I have commented icon attribute line, but still it did not worked. Is there any other plugin or external program required to make it work?

Comment: Mr. Noddy, please post the output of the error. It's really hard to just imagine what could be wrong.